# file send to 000webhost by filezilla

Tags: timeout, filezilla, hosting-services

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (145,14,144,27,202,206).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Connecting to port 31039
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I was able to login to my web server(000webhost.com) that's what I got first. But, when everything was loading then, `connection timed out`. My internet is working well. But, Why I am having the issue? I searched on Internet for a while. There was lot more questions like this but, none of them was helpful. Even, I watched some tutorial in YT also.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After doing above changes everything is working fine.